# Warning: Linker: (..) Unused DT entry

Tags: android, python, inteligencia-artificial, keras, python-3.7

Estaba creando un script python usando keras en [termux](https://termux.com) con theano como backend, porque no puedo instalar tensorflow en android, cuando lo voy a ejecutar me aparece:

```
Using Theano backend
WARNING: linker: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.theano/compiledir_Linux-3.18.19+-armv7l-with-libc--3.7.1-32/tmpmx5j8pis/m8dccfba9ba8331d682882b58b71f10b9964902caa05aab2e113780b563796fce.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x3ba
WARNING: linker: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.theano/compiledir_Linux-3.18.19+-armv7l-with-libc--3.7.1-32/tmp3y_u2m51/m8d1bf9e79b85f534dfe998575c7e7ea4dd1c5d1dcc10f88b36d113cbd6c7a993.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x362
Epoch 1/100
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 4.8022
...
Epoch 100/100
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 3.1974e-14
WARNING: linker: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.theano/compiledir_Linux-3.18.19+-armv7l-with-libc--3.7.1-32/tmpci2gf174/m5e618a30457958f05755e24c8e216abe250732682e64206030484fe296085b50.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x33d
11       # Resultado
```

**¿Cómo soluciono o oculto estos warnings?**

**Aquí dejo todos los archivos:**

**~/.keras/keras.json**

```
{
    "floatx": "float32",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "backend": "theano",
    "image_data_format": "channels_last"
}
```

**~/nn.py**

```
import keras
import numpy as np

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(1, input_dim=1)
])

mse = keras.losses.mean_squared_error
sgd = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

model.compile(loss=mse, optimizer=sgd)

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])

model.fit(x, y, epochs=5, batch_size=1)
result = model.predict([6])
print(int(round(result[0][0])))
```

**No existe o no sé donde está** **.theanorc**

**Python 3.7.1**

**Keras 2.2.4**

**Theano 1.0.3**

**Clang 7.0.0**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

el problema era que había instalado keras antes de theano.

Para llegar a esto desinstalé keras, y lo volví a instalar estando theano instalado.

Comment: y como fue que llegaste a esa conclusión?

Comment: Llegué a esto porque desinstalé keras y lo volví a instalar estando theano instalado

Comment: pues añade esa explicación a tu respuesta